# How do I backup Android Studio itself

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, backup

I don't have that fast internet and need to format my PC. It's running on Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to backup the installation of Android Studio so that when i format my pc and install ubuntu again, i could use it again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

copy `/usr/local/android-studio` and all its childs to your backup folder

also backup /home/user/.AndroidStudio*.* and /home/user/Android